# When i import Settings.System currentTimeMillis isn't working anymore

Tags: java, android, time, import, identification

I used to have this Line of Code:

```
parameters.put("time",Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

When i added some new Features, to name it phone identification by AndroidID i had to import following:

```
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.provider.Settings.System;
```

after this change, the System.currentTimeMillis() is said to be not resolvable.

Why is this happening and how can i prevent it from doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to access both `android.provider.Settings.System` and `java.lang.System`, one or the other will need to be accessed using its fully-qualified name. For example, you can import `android.provider.Settings.System` as you currently have it, and change your `System.currentTimeMillis()` call to:

```
parameters.put("time", Long.toString(java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis()));
```